# W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.CAMERA to package <my package name> because it was previously installed without

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I cannot get rid of this error:

*W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.CAMERA to package  because it was previously installed without*

This error is preventing me from accessing the camera from my app.  I tried uninstalling the apk with adb uninstall and I get:

*Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]*

I then tried changing the package name to install a new apk.  I still get the same error in the new app.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try with rebooting AT device because

> Dangerous permissions requested by apps are not granted until the next device reboot.This includes new app installs and new  elements in existing apps.

see [AT Release Note](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html)

Also, You can install application with granting permission using adb command line as below

adb install -g yourapk.apk

Answer (score 1):

If you have rebooted and the Permissions issue(s) still exist, do the following steps:

1. Reboot
2. Connect via adb: **adb connect Android.local:5555**
3. Uninstall the apk:  **adb uninstall (you package name)**
4. reboot
5. install your apk
6. reboot

Happy Coding!